# Bug: Cannot unhide temporarily hidden links

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

A message in my careers message box has some hidden links that show as <link temporarily hidden>. I've tried clicking 'I'm interested; show the complete message' but nothing happens.

I've tried using Chrome 4.0.249.49 (35163) beta, Safari 4.0.4 (6531.21.10), and Firefox 2.6 (all on OS X 10.6.2).

How do I show the hidden links?

**Edit**: Aha! Viewing the source shows a potential problem with the HTML:

```
<span class='temporarily-hidden'>&lt;email temporarily <span class='temporarily-hidden'>&lt;link temporarily hidden&gt;</span> <<span class='temporarily-hidden'>&lt;link temporarily hidden&gt;</span>
```

Note the extra `<` before the last `span`. Is Jeff parsing HTML with regexes? ;)

**Another edit**: Posting a message through the reply form unhides the links. (Unless the problem was coincidentally fixed while I was writing).

Comment: Yes this is very confusing - there should be a better explanation of the process - that you have to respond with interest to get the hidden links to show..

Answer (score 1):

Probably a bug, but dependent on the content of the message, eg, the message itself might have had malformed markup.

Since there is a workaround (to respond), and it's dependent on the message itself (which we can't control), I'm marking this complete for now.